# qtm not plotting within function with return value

Tags: r, tmap

I'm trying to plot maps using `qtm()` of the `tmap` R package within a function. For some reason setting a return value for the function prevents the plotting.

Minimal (non) working example:

```
graphics.off()
library("tmap")
data(World)
# this works: 
a<-function(){qtm(World)}
a()

graphics.off()
# but this won't do anything: 
a<-function(){qtm(World);return(1)}
a()
```

Any idea how that could be or how to investigate the issue?

Comment: As explained in the R-FAQ, the results of some plotting functions may require a `print`-call when the plot is constructed inside a function.

Comment: Exactly! `a<-function(){print(qtm(World))}; a()` will work.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Martijn and 42- in the comments adding a print does the trick:

```
a<-function(){print(qtm(World))}; a()
```